# Super Confusion On If Statement

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

I am very confused on this one. I have a few formulas that run a base number value and either add or subtract from that base value. The lines of code run fine if I ONLY run the code that subtracts (I have around 7 numbers in each set of data) I can confirm the outputs of only 4 out of 7 subtract, but when I run all four formulas I walk away with a table that everything has +1 added. So everything in my data set has +1, even though when I run this with ONLY the subtract I only adjust the four that meet the condition and it does not execute on the other 3 that do not meet the condition. Why is it adding +1 to all when they do not meet that condition when I add in the 3rd and 4th equations?

```
    if home_team_shots_on_goal.values / away_team_shots_on_goal.values <= 0.95 or home_team_shots_on_goal.values / away_team_shots_on_goal.values >= 1.05:
        home_team_ppg = home_team_ppg - 0.5

    if away_team_shots_on_goal.values / home_team_shots_on_goal.values <= 0.95 or away_team_shots_on_goal.values / home_team_shots_on_goal.values >= 1.05:
        away_team_ppg = away_team_ppg - 0.5

    if home_team_shots_on_goal.values / away_team_shots_on_goal.values <= 1.05 or home_team_shots_on_goal.values / away_team_shots_on_goal.values >= 0.95:
        home_team_ppg = home_team_ppg + 0.5

    if away_team_shots_on_goal.values / home_team_shots_on_goal.values <= 1.05 or away_team_shots_on_goal.values / home_team_shots_on_goal.values >= 0.95:
        away_team_ppg = away_team_ppg + 0.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a math problem more than an if problem. From your first clause:

```
home_team_shots_on_goal.values / away_team_shots_on_goal.values <= 0.95
```

From your third clause:

```
home_team_shots_on_goal.values / away_team_shots_on_goal.values <= 1.05
```

If the first clause is true, so is the third, because `0.95` is less than `1.05`:

```
(calculated_ratio) <= 0.95 <= 1.05
```

That means if your first clause subtracts 0.5, your third clause will add 0.5. Your whole thing bears this problem, which is probably solved by using `elif` instead of new `if` clauses - but to properly say you should put in some input values and what you expect as output.

FWIW with a bit of value assignment and shorter hand this becomes clearer in the code:

```
home_away_ratio = home_team_shots_on_goal.values / away_team_shots_on_goal.values
away_home_ratio = away_team_shots_on_goal.values / home_team_shots_on_goal.values

if not (0.95 < home_away_ratio < 1.05):  # Is the ratio outside these values?
    home_team_ppg +=  -0.5
... and so on
```

Comment: @Ford Math always did kick my butt. Laughing at myself once you point it out so clearly. I will need to look into then how to write it as if that number falls between 0.95 or 1.05 do X, if not do this. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yep! Good luck @Josh

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get what I needed with that elif! Kudos.